# Filtering for Month for timestamp column

Tags: sql, presto

I use the Month function like below to filter for a month as:

```
Where MONTH(timestampcolumn) = '9'
```

If I want to do same but filter for month based on name like September how would I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) to convert the timestamp into a month name using the `%M` format string:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(timestampcolumn, '%M') = 'September'
```